# Issues setting up ASP.net Membership and MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, database

I'm currently working on a school project which I almost finished. I tested it and it was working fine on my local machine. Then I uploaded it to a webserver to test it and I got an error. 
Apparantly you have to configure an external MySQL server and database to get the **ASP.net membership** system working. (I know it's stupid but I honestly didn't know). 
So now I've managed to get a free database (since it's for school purposes it doesn't matter) and I want to save the required information for the **membership service** in this external database.
So now I have to do these three things:

1.Getting to know which columns from the **local** database I have to insert in the **external** database (e..g. username: VARCHAR(20) etc.) 
I need to get this info from my local  database...
2 replacing the connectionstring in my web.config file to get it working with my **external** database.

I searched the web a lot but couldn't find the right thing to do:
 **GETTING TO KNOW THE COLUMNS**
I read online it was useful to use Microsoft SQL server management. I downloaded it so I could connect to my local (automatically generated) database. I couldn't figure out how to log in. Using my machine name or just a '.' both doesn't work....
**edit: this is what I mean (picture) what should I do?**[image: what should I fill in?]

**REPLACING THE CONNECTIONSTRING**
To be honest, I don't understand the connectionstring at all...

If anyone know what to do in these two problems I would really appreciate the help!

Thanks in advance,
Elias

Comment: Connecting to your local PC is called `.` (just a single period), or `(local)`

Answer (score 0):

You seemed to ask several questions (above) so I will try to answer enough of them to get you pointed in the right direction.

First, MySQL is not the same as SQL Server.  They are different/competing products.  From your comments, it sounds like you need to attach a .MDF file which is a "Microsoft Database File".  Instead of MySQL, you need to install SQL Express (free). SQL Management Studio will allow you to attach your .MDF file and set up permissions, etc.

Since this is for school, you can use your DB mgr to create a test account with a simple PW. It could be something simple like User: `Demo`, Pw: `D3mooo{` (or whatever you can remember). By default Sql Server only allows you to grant permissions to accounts from your OS.  To change that, you can use SSMS, right-click the server, choose Properties, security and change the "Server authentication" to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode".  Otherwise, you could just grant permission to your IIS server's identity, which is usually some name like `[machinename\IUSR]` (with square-brackets).

Once that is set, you need to create a "connection string".  The easiest way is to create a text file on your desktop and rename it from `new text Document.txt` to `dsn.udl`.  The file extension is the trick, it must be .udl instead of .txt.  If you get it right, the icon will change and you can double-click it and go through the wizard to make/test a connection string. When you are done, you can open the udl file with notepad, and it will contain a working connection string. Copy the connection string into your web.config and things should start working for your membership DB.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I downloaded MySQL workbench and connected to my local system (I think...) but where can I see the table? It is located in ~/Documents/Visual Studio 2017/Website 7/database.mdf 
I understand you can't open a .mdf file but you have to attach it? I'm sorry, I'm not familiar with SQL and I have some real noob struggles ;)

Comment: Ok. If you have a .mdf file, that will only run with SQL Server, not MySQL.  You need to download and install SQL Express.  Once that is in-place, you can use SQL Mgt Studio to "attach" your .mdf (database file)

Comment: Also, you won't need to download the MySQL drivers.  The drivers for connecting to Sql Server are build-into Windows.  I'm going to edit my question (above) to remove that advice.

Comment: okay thank you, I think I know how it works now. But how should I connect to my local machine? I edited my question above, I hope you understand what I mean. Many thanks for the help!

Comment: yep, I got it working. It's '.\SQLEXPRESS'. thank you!

Comment: I changed my answer a little to give better instructions for granting permissions, or setting a user account.